# Simple Dom Parser or CURL TABLE PARSING

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, html-table, simple-html-dom

I need help to get the data from a table. It's an internet usage table and the html code is down below :

```
 <table width="572" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody><tr valign="top">
   <td width="1" class="bgsidelines"></td>
   <td width="*" class="bgbottom">
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td width="10" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"></td>
          <td width="443">
  <table width="443" height="10" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td width="100%" class="path"><b>Internet usage</b></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="reg"><!--  Begin yours codes  -->
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>

   <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0">
    <tbody>                 
     <tr>
  <td width="43" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="60" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="60" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="reg" nowrap="nowrap">2017-06-01 to<br>2017-
  06-18</td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">54815.06</td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">53.53</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">52114.59</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">50.89</td>            
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">106929.65</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">104.42</td>           
 </tr>           
 </tbody></table></td></tr>
</tbody></table> 

   <!--  End yours codes  -->
       </tr>
       </tbody></table></td></tr>
      </tbody></table></td></tr>
     </tbody></table>
```

I've done it in a way that works but only works sometimes, this must be due to the user agent. and it fetches the entire table while I would like each separated values for the internet usage, the ones in the td class="reg"  (54815.06, 53.53..) It's hard because there is a table in table.. Also it's

My PHP   :

```
 require_once 'advanced_html_dom.php';
 $numvl = $_POST['numvl'];
 $url = 
 'https://extranet.videotron.com/services/secur/extranet/tpia/Usage.do?
 compteInternet='.$numvl;

 $html = new AdvancedHtmlDom();
 $html->load_file($url);
 $element = $html->find("tr");
 echo $element[1]->innertext;
```

Comment: Can you search for the class, i.e., ->find("td.reg")

Comment: I tried that a week ago... it gives the same output.. I don't understand why My problem must be when I use   echo $element[1] - > innertext;
There must be something to parse again in this element at index 1 of the element[ ] array ?... I'm not far from my answer.. because it displays the whole tab, but I'd like to just be able to store the values.

Comment: You're using it wrong: `$html->find('tr', 1)->text`

Answer (score 0):

no need for some external lib (`advanced_html_dom.php`? never heard of), just use PHP's DOMDocument and DOMXPath.

example:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML(getHTML());
$xpath=new DOMXPath($domd);
foreach($xpath->query("//td[@valign='top' and @class='reg']") as $ele){
    var_dump($ele->textContent);
}


function getHTML():string{
$html=<<<'HTML'
 <table width="572" border="0" align="center" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody><tr valign="top">
   <td width="1" class="bgsidelines"></td>
   <td width="*" class="bgbottom">
    <table summary="" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td width="10" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"></td>
          <td width="443">
  <table width="443" height="10" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td width="100%" class="path"><b>Internet usage</b></td>
     </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="reg"><!--  Begin yours codes  -->
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>

   <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0">
    <tbody>                 
     <tr>
  <td width="43" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="44" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="60" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>MB</center></b>
  </td>
  <td width="60" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" class="grey"><b><center>GB</center></b>
  </td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="reg" nowrap="nowrap">2017-06-01 to<br>2017-
  06-18</td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">54815.06</td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">53.53</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">52114.59</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">50.89</td>            
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">106929.65</td>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" valign="top" class="reg">104.42</td>           
 </tr>           
 </tbody></table></td></tr>
</tbody></table> 

   <!--  End yours codes  -->
       </tr>
       </tbody></table></td></tr>
      </tbody></table></td></tr>
     </tbody></table>
HTML;
return $html;
}
```

output:

```
string(8) "54815.06"
string(5) "53.53"
string(8) "52114.59"
string(5) "50.89"
string(9) "106929.65"
string(6) "104.42"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I will try this and let you know !